# How to get the software center to work for Ubuntu 11.04 (or any older version)?

Tags: 11.04, apt, 10.04, software-center

I can't install Ubuntu because of UEFI. So, I'm using vm-ware. Sadly, it runs slow on newer versions of Ubuntu. 11.04 & 10.04 run great.

Problem is: I can't use the software center. I tried replacing "ubuntu.com" with "old-releases.ubuntu.com" in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
Nothing. I run `sudo apt-get update`. This is what I get: http://pastebin.com/jLRf3MwG

I would install everything manually, but most of the software I use provide installation through Ubuntu repositories only.

Comment: Sorry, but if it doesn't work is for a good reason (aka dependencies) You may want to use Lubuntu or Xubuntu if the VM is too slow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replaced it wrong, the ubuntu.com subdomains should be replaced with "old-releases". For example: "http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/" not "http://archive.old-releases.ubuntu.com/" .

Please note that this method will result in some duplicate entries.